# How to count the total post made by each user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to count the total post made by each member, for instance,

member table,

```
member_id
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

post table,

```
post_id         member_id
1               1
2               1
3               1
4               2
5               3
```

the result I am after,

```
member_id       totalPost
1               3
2               1
3               1
4               0
5               0
6               0
```

My working query,

```
SELECT *
FROM root_members_cfm  AS m

LEFT JOIN root_posts AS n
ON n.member_id = m.member_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
   count(post_id) as totalPost,
   m.member_id
from
   member as m 
left join 
   post on post.member_id=m.member_id 
group by m.member_id;
```